# enlarge an image - getting a "IndexError: invalid index to scalar variable"

Tags: python-3.x, image-processing

I am trying to write a function that receives an image and an integer and by this formula: [image: formula], to enlarge the original image.
i and j are the indexes of the pixel, y and x (small or big) are the cols and the rows of the original picture and the big picture.
every pixel should be enlarged by a.
I am trying to test the function but i receieve ""IndexError: invalid index to scalar variable"
why is that? thank you for helping!

```
   def nearest_enlarge(img, a):
    new_im= np.zeros(img.shape)
    for i in range(img.shape[0]):
            for j in range(img.shape[1]):
                    smallpixelvalue= img[i,j]
                    new_im[i,j]= smallpixelvalue[np.floor(i*(img.shape[0]/img.shape[0]*a)),np.floor(j*(img.shape[1]/img.shape[1]*a))]
    return new_im
```

Comment: If you enlarge an image surely it will need to be created with a larger size than the original?

Comment: yes , we need to assume that 'a' is larger than 1

Comment: So we need to check this line... `new_im= np.zeros(img.shape)`

Comment: tried this: 
shape= (a * img.shape[0], a * img.shape[1])
new_im= np.zeros(shape) - still getting the same error